# What is the capacity size of my Maytag washer model number MTW574OTQO

Tags: washing-machine

Model MTW574OTQO.   SERIAL CW2542489 need capacity size

Comment: Read the manual or look it up with google.

Comment: not a home improvement question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP could have searched for the answer faster than writing up a question here.

Comment: @crip659 I found the user manual for it in my search, but I did not see where it listed the capacity. If I had found it in the manual, I would have listed that as my source and considered it authoritative.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure those "o"s are "0"s. Based on my research, MTW5740TQ0 has a capacity of 3.6 cubic feet. I can't find an authoritative source, but found the capacity listed on a replacement tub that fits that model.